# How to start with BST file

Tags: bibtex

I am writing a paper for a journal. The support team of this journal sent me a BST file, for reference, but I am a newbie with LaTex and have no idea how to start.

I put the BST file into the same directory with my TEX file, and then do not know how to continue.

My environment is: Mac OS 10.10, MacTex + TexMaker 4.4.1.

Thank you very much.

Updated: You can download a whole ZIP file include BST file at

http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/journal/10.1002/(ISSN)1532-0634/homepage/wileyjbst.zip

Comment: This is covered in every LaTeX introduction, and answering this here does not quite conform to the standards of the site. Please have a look at [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html) and [LaTeX for writing a PhD thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/index.html). If you have more specific questions, you are welcome to ask. ;-)

Comment: I couldn't dig up an existing question that spells it out, so look [here](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/localadditions.html); you must create and register your own "root" folder for packages, and place the bst file in the subdirectory `bibtex/bst` under the root folder.

Comment: @alexis for a one-off document it's simpler just to put it in the same directory as the tex document, no need to install it in the standard directory layout.

Comment: @Johannes_B: thank you very much for your comment, but I looked through both documents you suggested, and I still do not find how to use BST file. In the second one (Latex for PhD thesis), the author guided how to write bibtex (I already know), but I think he did not mention BST file.

Comment: I looked at the resources and the word bst is never really mentioned, though the use is explained. This will be hard for a beginner.  I am going to write a note to the author. Meanwhile, you can read [the wikibook article](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management), but i haven't checked it for correctness.

Comment: @Johannes_B thank you for your understanding. I will try.

Comment: A .bst file is used with `\bibliographystyle{filename}` where `filename` is the name of your bst file.  How does it come into play in your document?  When, after using `\cite{}` for some reference material, you later invoke `\bibliography{}`, where the bibliographic data is stored in a file which is the argument to `\bibliography`.  The .bst file tells LaTeX how to convert your bibliographic data into a reference list.